# How to take an input of line separated integers as a list in python

Tags: python, list

You are given a set of integers separated by lines as input,for example....

```
7
2
4
5
8
9
```

but you want to get all these converted to a lst for your program, like [7,2,4,5,8,9] after several attempts, e.g.

```
nums = int (input())
lst = []
for i in nums:
    lst.append(int (i))
print (list)
```

Unfortunately, this outputs only the first element of the input `[7]`
Even tried to use a range, no difference 
Please, what i am getting wrong?

Comment: You can't read numbers separated by newline through `input()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` only returns one line. You would need to *repeatedly* call `input` to get each line, until `input` returns an empty string.

However, it's much easier to use the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fileinput.html) module, which can read either from standard input *or* from one or more files passed as arguments.

```
import fileinput

lst = [int(x) for x in fileinput.input()]
```

Then, if your numbers are in a file named `numbers.txt`, you can run your script with either

```
script.py < numbers.txt
```

to read the numbers from standard input, or

```
script.py numbers.txt
```

to have the `fileinput` module open the file and read from it directly. If fact, if you have multiple files, you could pass them all and `fileinput` would read them one after the other with the same loop:

```
script numbers.txt more_numbers.txt even_more_numbers.txt
```